# Laravel Download file issue

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am having an issue downloading files in my storage folder. I get no error messages. All that happens is a redirect to the 404 page. The file exists in the path given so I am stumped. I have tried removing $document from the second argument in the response() but has not worked. What do I need to do? Strangely when running on local host it works?

```
public function download(Request $request, $document)
{
    $pathToFile = storage_path() . '/' . 'app/documents/client'.'/'.$document;
     if (file_exists($pathToFile))
    {       
        return response()->download($pathToFile, $document);
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
        return redirect('errors.404');
    }
}
```

File System

```
 'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Route:

```
Route::get('documents/client/{document}',       'ClientDocumentController@download')->name('client.docs');
```

Comment: Log your `$pathToFile`  and see if it really exists, and what the permissions are.

Comment: check the file is exists in the correct location?

Comment: The file exists. However is this Route correct? Updated in question

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. You might want to throw some logging into your function: assign `$document = null` in your function call (just in case), then log the document, pathToFile, and how far it gets. I'm a big fan of `Log::info()` because you can place a bunch of markers and then watch your log file to see where things break.

Comment: I haven't used log::info would it be something like $document = null;
   Log::info($pathToFile = storage_path() . '/' . 'app/documents/client'.'/'.$document);

I am getting a 302 to the log in page when using Chrom dev tools.

Comment: It would be `public function download(Request $request, $document = null) { Log::info($document); $pathToFile = storage_path() . '/' . 'app/documents/client'.'/'.$document; Log::info($pathToFile);`. However, if you're getting a 302, that's a completely different ball of wax.

Comment: Does the below answer make sense as an approach? @aynber

Comment: Im pretty sure you can direct to a Controller function without submitting a form (below answer). Make sure your route is unique or  high enough up the chain, so the href doesn't trigger some other route/Controller function

Answer (score -1):

Here is an approach to downloading files to whom it may help.

The initial issue is that the href in the anchor tags was creating a link to the url, yet the document was not accessible via a normal url because it was in Storage. The code then  redirected to 404 as is it could not find the url resource (Storage is not publicly available). The controller never received the request because href doesn't send requests to controllers.

So using form action this sends the request to download to the controller which in turn processes the GET from Storage.

```
 <form action="{{ route('client.docs', [$document->document] ) }}" method="GET" role="form" id="form" >
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="hidden" placeholder="{{ $document->document}}" >
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="submit">
    Download<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```